# How can I customize my MUI Autocomplete in class component to accept new input and value in V5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a class component where I used a customized MUI Autocomplete. It was working fine in V4 but after I switch to V5 there is bug in the code.

Here is my custom Autocomplete code

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const SingleSoloSelect2 = (props) => {
  const filter = (options, params) => {
      let inList = false;
      const filtered = options.filter(o => {
          if (!params.inputValue) return true;

          const value = o[props.labelField].toLowerCase();
          const input = params.inputValue.toLowerCase();
          if (value === input) inList = true;
          if (value.includes(input)) return true;

          return false;
      });

      return { inList, filtered };
  }

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            fullWidth
            freeSolo={props.freeSolo !== undefined ? props.freeSolo : true}
            id={props.id}
            value={props.value}
            options={props.options || []}
            disabled={props.disabled}
            selectOnFocus
            clearOnBlur
            handleHomeEndKeys
            onChange={(e, v) => {
                let isNew = false;
              if (typeof v === 'string') {
                isNew = v;
        //        delete v;
              } else if (v && v.inputValue) {
                isNew = v.inputValue;
            //    delete v.inputValue;
              } else {
                isNew = v;
              }
              props.onChange(v, isNew, props.id);
            }}
            getOptionLabel={props.getOptionLabel}
            filterOptions={(options, params) => {
                const { inList, filtered } = filter(options, params);
                if (props.freeSolo === undefined || props.freeSolo === true) {
                    if (params.inputValue !== '' && !inList) {
                        filtered.push({
                            [props.valueField]: params.inputValue,
                            [props.labelField]: params.inputValue,
                            new: true,
                        });
                    }
                }

                return filtered;
            }}
            renderOption={(option) => {
              return option.new
                  ? `Add "${option[props.labelField]}"`
                  : option[props.labelField];
              }
            }
            isOptionEqualToValue={props.isOptionEqualToValue}
            renderInput={(params) => (<TextField {...params} label={props.label} variant={props.variant} size={props.size} error={props.error} />)}
          />
        );
      }

export default SingleSoloSelect2;
```

In my main component I used it as

```
                            <SingleSoloSelect2
                                id="free-solo-with-text-demo"
                                label="my label"
                                options={options}
                                value={value || null}
                                onChange={this.handleSingleSelect}
                                labelField="name"
                                valueField="name"
                                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                            />
```

My option is an array of objects like

```
[{id: 1, name: name1},
...
]
```

The `this.handleSingleSelect` is defined as

```
handleSingleSelect = (v, isNew) => {
        const q = this.state.activeQuestion;
        q.value = v;
        if (isNew) q.options.push(q.value);
        this.setState({ activeQuestion: q });
    }
```

1. When I load the form, the option label is blank but I can see it in the console when selected.
2. When I add new input I am not seeing the Add and input label on screen